# What is the node_modules folder for in Laravel?

Tags: node.js, laravel, phpstorm

When I open a new Laravel project in PhpStorm I am asked to run `npm install` to install project dependencies. I am assuming that Laravel has some node.js dependencies but searching on Google I can't find a definitive answer.

1. Are these node.js modules part of the Laravel project or some PhpStorm functionality?
2. What part does it play in Laravel and/or PhpStorm?

I'm using Laravel 5.7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The default install of Laravel includes a starter Vue.js application, as well as Webpack and [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix). These use Node.

If you don't intend to use these, you can safely remove `node_modules`, the starter Vue app, and `package.json` in your Laravel install.

They have nothing to do with PHPStorm.

> **edit:** In recent versions of Laravel, the command `php artisan preset none` [will remove the Vue starter app](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend).

Answer (score 11):

When you install laravel you will got a folder called **vendor** in your project. In this folder you have got all the **pacakge dependencies of the laravel**. And All those packages and their dependencies are listed in **composer.json**.

Same as **node_modules** folder also contains the package dependencies related to your javascript projects. So, that you can require it in your projects. And All those packages and their dependencies are listed in **package.json**.

In your case if you are not using vue.js,react.js then you don't need to run **npm install** . You can start building project without worrying about node_modules. You can even delete this folder and install it again using **npm install** when required.

Comment: Actually we need the `node_modules` folder to use `jquery` and `bootstrap` even if we are not using `vue`.

Comment: If you use Laravel Mix, Bootstrap or jQuery, you will need the node_modules, at some point.